# не добавляються записи в MySQL через html-форму

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Не добавляються записи в MySQL из формы html. Перепробовал все, у меня даже пустая строка не создаеться в базе данных. До последнего не хотел писать сюда, хотел разобраться сам.. но уже сил моих больше нету) 
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? php 5.3 mysql 5.5
знаю, сейчас скажете используй PDO, но я пока только учусь, и хочу знать и это, а потом уже PDO
вот код

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_products (title, price, seo_words, seo_description, mini_description, description, mini_features, features, visible) VALUES(                        
                            '".$_POST["form_title"]."',
                            '".$_POST["form_price"]."',
                            '".$_POST["form_seo_words"]."',
                            '".$_POST["form_seo_description"]."',
                            '".$_POST["txt1"]."',
                            '".$_POST["txt2"]."',
                            '".$_POST["txt3"]."',
                            '".$_POST["txt4"]."',
                            '".$chk_visible."',                                                 
                        )",$link);

      $_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-success'>Товар успешно добавлен!</p>";
      $id = mysql_insert_id();
```

и html код

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<ul id="edit-tovar">

<li>
<label>Название товара</label>
<input type="text" name="form_title" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Цена</label>
<input type="text" name="form_price"  />
</li>

<li>
<label>Ключевые слова</label>
<input type="text" name="form_seo_words"  />
</li>

<li>
<label>Краткое описание</label>
<textarea name="form_seo_description"></textarea>
</li>
</ul> 
<label class="stylelabel" >Основная картинка</label>

<div id="baseimg-upload">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000"/>
<input type="file" name="upload_image" />

</div>

<h3 class="h3click" >Краткое описание товара</h3>
<div class="div-editor1" >
<textarea id="editor1" name="txt1" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1" );
            AjexFileManager.init({
                returnTo: "ckeditor",
                editor: ckeditor1
            });
        </script>
 </div>       

<h3 class="h3click" >Описание товара</h3>
<div class="div-editor2" >
<textarea id="editor2" name="txt2" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( "editor2" );
            AjexFileManager.init({
                returnTo: "ckeditor",
                editor: ckeditor1
            });
        </script>
 </div>          

<h3 class="h3click" >Краткие характеристики</h3>
<div class="div-editor3" >
<textarea id="editor3" name="txt3" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( "editor3" );
            AjexFileManager.init({
                returnTo: "ckeditor",
                editor: ckeditor1
            });
        </script>
 </div>        

<h3 class="h3click" >Характеристики</h3>
<div class="div-editor4" >
<textarea id="editor4" name="txt4" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( "editor4" );
            AjexFileManager.init({
                returnTo: "ckeditor",
                editor: ckeditor1
            });
        </script>
  </div> 

<label class="stylelabel" >Галлерея картинок</label>

<div id="objects" >

<div id="addimage1" class="addimage">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"/>
<input type="file" name="galleryimg[]" />
</div>

</div>

<p id="add-input" >Добавить</p>

<h3 class="h3title" >Настройки товара</h3>   
<ul id="chkbox">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_visible" id="chk_visible" /><label for="chk_visible" >Показывать товар</label></li>
</ul> 


    <p align="right" ><input type="submit" id="submit_form" name="submit_add" value="Добавить товар"/></p>     
</form>
```

Comment: а что возвращает mysql_query() ? `mysql_query() возвращает TRUE в случае успеха и FALSE в случае ошибки. ` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: mysql_last_error или что то вроде того попробуйте вызвать и посмотреть что возвращает.

Answer (score 1):

Там где `'".$chk_visible."',` убери запятую, запрос ожидает еще одно поле, а у тебя уже все написано.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас запрос с ошибкой.

Строка **'".$chk_visible."',**  содержит  лишнюю запятую в конце.
Исправьте запрос на такой :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_products (title, price, seo_words, seo_description, mini_description, description, mini_features, features, visible) VALUES(                        
                        '".$_POST["form_title"]."',
                        '".$_POST["form_price"]."',
                        '".$_POST["form_seo_words"]."',
                        '".$_POST["form_seo_description"]."',
                        '".$_POST["txt1"]."',
                        '".$_POST["txt2"]."',
                        '".$_POST["txt3"]."',
                        '".$_POST["txt4"]."',
                        '".$chk_visible."'                                                 
                    )",$link);
```